# Calling sub function in ControllerAs AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controlleras

Hey I am new to angularjs Im using controlleras style in angularjs as the code is presentable and net. My problem is calling subfunction in controller my code as follow

```
 //AngularJS CODE
      (function(){
         'use strict';

         angular.module('mAPP', ['ngMaterial']);

         function helpM(){
            var vm = this; 
            vm.SaveM = function(){
                alert('Save Me Now');
            }
         }

        function SaveCTRL(){
          var vm = this; 

          vm.nineOne = helpM.SaveM;
        }

        angular.module('mAPP')
                .controller('SaveCTRL', [SaveCTRL]); 

      })();
```

//HTML CODE

```
     <div ng-controller="SaveCTRL as main" layout="column" ng-cloak="" class="md-inline-form" ng-app="mAPP">


     <md-button class="md-raised md-primary" ng-click="main.nineOne()">Submit</md-button>

     </div>
```

But the alert doesnt execute thanks a lot in advance :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to make an instance of `helpM` otherwise `this` will be `undefined`

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('myApp', []);

  function helpM() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.SaveM = function() {
      alert('Save Me Now');
    }
    return vm;
  }


  function SaveCTRL() {
    var vm = this;

    vm.nineOne = new helpM().SaveM;

    return vm;
  }

  angular.module('myApp')
    .controller('SaveCTRL', SaveCTRL);

})();
```

```html
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
  <div ng-controller="SaveCTRL as main" layout="column" ng-cloak="" class="md-inline-form">


    <md-button class="md-raised md-primary" ng-click="main.nineOne()">Submit</md-button>

  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: so treat a function like a class that needs to be instance to get the value of this ? thanks it works

Answer (score 0):

You need to instantiate the helpM Class:

Replace:

```
vm.nineOne = helpM.SaveM
```

To:

```
var helpObj = new helpM();
vm.nineOne = helpObj.SaveM.bind(helpObj);
```

Comment: thanks but I encounter an error it says Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined